# Install-WindowsFeature : Containers - Error: The parameter is incorrect. Error: 0x80070057

Tags: powershell, docker, windows-server-2016

I am trying to enable Containers feature in Windows Server 2016 but I am getting the following error:

```
Install-WindowsFeature : The request to add or remove features on the specified server failed.
Installation of one or more roles, role services, or features failed.
The parameter is incorrect. Error: 0x80070057
```

I have tried `CHKDSK /R`, `sfc /scannow`, adding `CopyFileBufferedSynchronousIo` to Registry, adding Decimal to clock but nothing worked.

Please help.

Update: The machine is a Hyper-V VM

Comment: please include the command that you ran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to answer this as it took a lot of effort and scanning of a largest file CBS.log

Soon after I got the error, I opened the CBS.log file where I found one error

```
00000127 Regenerating payload files from delta files on component: [l:99 ml:140]'msil_microsoft.containers.powershell.objects_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.14393.1378_none_6190106d2f9631c7'
```

and also my error:

```
00000128@2020/5/13:11:06:02.934 (F) onecore\base\wcp\componentstore\deltastore.cpp(2879): Error STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER originated in function ComponentStore::CRawStoreLayout::RecursivelyRegenerateComponentPayload expression: Parameter check failed
```

I searched on Google and found this link 
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-update-kb-4022725/a40f7c81-0de8-4b87-bead-802f0898471d

As per the link:

I need to get the registry name in the error which is this in my first error:

```
msil_microsoft.containers.powershell.objects_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.14393.1378_none_6190106d2f9631c7
```

I had to change the CF value to 880 in

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\COMPONENTS\DerivedData\Components\msil_microsoft.containers.powershell.objects_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.14393.1378_none_6190106d2f9631c7
```

To get the **COMPONENTS** key, just open the Turn Windows Features on or Off and voila you got this.

A big one